# The meaning of "Has Transfer Access" and maybe a possible bug in the free developer organization?

Tags: apex, bug, userrecordaccess

I am new to Salesforce/Apex and I am messing with the User Record Access. There is a field called "HasTransferAccess", but the description of it is not very helpful. What does it actually mean?

Also, I am using a free Dev Org and I found a strange conflict. The user that created the whole org we will call User A. I go and create a User B. When I look at the User Record Access with the User Id as User A and the Record ID as User B, it says that the "Has Transfer Access" is false. However, when I look at the "Max Access Level" and "HasAllAccess" it says "All" and "true", respectively. Doesn't that cause a conflict because it says it says it doesn't have Transfer Access, but it says it has All access at the same time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that HasTransferAccess should indicate whether or not you could transfer ownership of a record as a given user. This is a special permission, and is normally reserved for Record Owners and Administrators.

But I believe the reason you are finding HasTransferAccess is false in the instance of a user record is not a bug, but rather a reflection that not being possible with the User sObject. Probably due to the fact that User has no owner field.

Comment: That was my initial thought as well, but in another org I am working on, the HasTransferAccess is true for the user record. That is what is throwing me off. Also, in the API, the "HasAllAccess" is defined as having "read, edit, delete, and transfer". That should be false in the case of the free dev org situation, no?

Comment: Curious. Are both orgs Developer Edition (DE) orgs?